# dict.pop() report an exceptional keyerror

Tags: python, python-3.x

I tried to solve the twoSum problem in leetcode
[Two Sum - LeetCode](https://leetcode.com/problems/two-sum/)

> Given an array of integers, return **indices** of the two numbers such that they add up to a specific target.
>
> You may assume that each input would have **exactly** one solution, and you may not use the *same* element twice.
>
> **Example:**
>
> ```
> Given nums = [2, 7, 11, 15], target = 9,
>
> Because nums[0] + nums[1] = 2 + 7 = 9,
> return [0, 1].
> ```

My solution:
1. Fix first number then to search (target -first)
2. Employ hash table to look up the index

```
class Solution():
    def twoSum(self, nums: List[int], target: int) -> List[int]:
        # nums_d: {value:index} 
        nums_d = {nums[i]:i for i in range(len(nums))}
        for i in range(len(nums)):
            find = target - nums[i]
            print('find: ', find)
            nums_d.pop(nums[i]) #Avoid use an element twice
            j = nums_d.get(find)#hash table to search 
            print('j: ',j)
            if j: 
                return [i, j]
        return None
```

and the testing codes

```
target = random.randrange(200,300)
nums = list(range(150))
nums = random.choices(nums, k=100)
solution = Solution()
print(solution.twoSum(nums, target))
```

It report KeyError when run it

```
In [131]: !python twoSum.py                                                                                                   
find:  168
j:  None
find:  183
j:  None
find:  216
j:  None
find:  163
j:  None
find:  182
j:  None
find:  169
j:  None
find:  235
j:  None
find:  169
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "twoSum.py", line 67, in <module>
    print(solution.twoSum(nums, target))
  File "twoSum.py", line 57, in twoSum
    nums_d.pop(nums[i]) #Avoid use an element twice
KeyError: 122
```

I cannot find the problem with line `nums_d.pop(nums[i])`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your dict size decreases with `pop` while `i` increases to the (original) length of the list, at some point you are going to be referencing an key which is higher than the size of the list, resulting in a `KeyError`.

What you want would be something like:

```
for i, k in enumerate(nums_d.keys()):
    # code stuff
```

This way you have `i` as the range to perform your indexing within `nums`, and you have `k` which refers to each key within `nums_d`, in order to use `pop` and avoid using an element twice.

Comment: so if the integers in nums are allowed to be duplicated, hash table will  not  be considered a solution?

Comment: Exactly, because inside your dict comprehension when there is a duplicate value, it will update the existing key inside the dictionary, not generate another key:value pair with the same key.